# Why does this repeatedly print newline?

Tags: c++, python, sockets

socket from c program sends 3 numbers to a socket in python.  code and output below:

python server code:

```
import SocketServer
import threading
import select
import sys

class TCPHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.rfile.readline()
        print "%s wrote:" % self.client_address[0]
        print (self.data)
        self.request.send(str(long(self.data)+1000))
        cur_connex.append({'ip': self.client_address, 'range': [long(self.data), long(self.data)+10000]})

        for a in cur_connex:
            print("%s did %d - %d on thread %s" % (a['ip'], a['range'][0], a['range'][1], threading.current_thread().name))

        while True:
            select.select([self.rfile], [], [])
            self.data = self.request.recv(10) #also tried "self.data = self.rfile.readline().strip("\n")" and without "strip()"
            print self.data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "", 50001
    cur_connex = []
    done_up_to = 0

    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 50001
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), TCPHandler)

    # Activate the server on new thread
    listen_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever, name='listen_th')
    listen_thread.start()
```

c++ client code:

```
for(unsigned long long i; i < perfect_numbers.size(); i++)
{
    cout << "i is " << i << " writing " << perfect_numbers[i] << "\n";

    for(int j = 0; j < perfect_numbers[i].size(); j++)
    {
        cout << perfect_numbers[i][j] << "|";
    }

    if(write(sock, perfect_numbers[i].c_str(), sizeof(perfect_numbers[i].c_str())) == -1)
    {
        cerr << "\nwrite failed: " << strerror(errno) << "\n";
        return -1;
    }
}

if(close(sock) == -1)
{
    cerr << "close sock error: " << strerror(errno) << "\n";
    return -1;
}

cout << "exiting...\n";
return 1;
```

server output:

```
>>> 127.0.0.1 wrote:
12695

('127.0.0.1', 55624) did 12695 - 22695 on thread listen_th
28
496
8128
```

...and then continuous newlines

client output:

```
that took 1.26624 seconds
i is 0 writing 28

2|8|
|i is 1 writing 496

4|9|6|
|i is 2 writing 8128

8|1|2|8|
|exiting...
```

I assume that last bit of the C++ client program is enough.  Also assuming it's something in that `while True` loop in the server.  New to both these languages, I know my coding isn't good yet, be gentle...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

<sup>*this post handles a bit more than what OP was asking for, I apologize for this matter. If you are only interested in how to fix the pending newlines written at the server please jump to section "**python**".*</sup>

---

**both client/server**

- You should add a delimiter between the numbers sent/received, there is nothing guaranteeing that each number will arrive individually. You may get two numbers in the same call to `self.request.recv (...)`.

---

**python**

- `print` will append a newline (`'\n'`) to every statement passed to it, unless you end the `print` statement with a comma.
- You should add a check to see if there really was any data to be read, if not there might have been an error or the connection has been closed.

  ```
  while True:
      select.select([self.rfile], [], [self.rfile])
      self.data = self.request.recv(10) 
      if self.data:
         print self.data
      else:
         # <close connection here>
  ```

---

**c++**

```
write(sock, perfect_numbers[i].c_str(), sizeof(perfect_numbers[i].c_str()))
```

- The above will always try to write `sizeof(char*)` characters to the socket `sock`, no matter if `perfect_numbers[i]` is one or a billion bytes of length.

  The third argument to `write` should be the number of bytes that you wish to be written, therefore you should use `perfect_numbers[i].size ()`. <sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> *I assume that you've been confused when looking at examples such as:*

```
 char buf[1024];

 ...

 write (sock, buf, sizeof (buf));
```

Comment: i thought recv() blocked if there was nothing to be read?  i also thought select blocked until there was something to be read?

Comment: @FrederickCraine if the connection has been closed or is prone to errors there is "something" to be read, but no data - just an error that has to be fixed. You are right `select.select` does block until there is something to be read, but if you are sending data faster than you are processing it you will end up with more than one "chunk" in the buffer you are reading.

Answer (score 1):

For stream request handlers, `self.request` is a [`socket`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html) object. The [`socket.recv`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv) function returns an empty string when the socket is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the output

i is 0 writing 28

2|8**|
|**i ...

I assume that perfect_numbers[i] ends with \n ("28\n" in this case). How the list is generated?